# "terminal-notifier.app is not open anymore"

Tags: bash, notifications, launchd

From a .plist loaded to `Launchd` I run a bash script which displays a notification using `terminal-notifier`.

The notification is displayed fine, but when clicked the message "terminal-notifier.app is not open anymore" pops up.

I tried to set a system app to open with `-sender 'com.apple.Terminal'` but the error message will still show up.

Comment: This does not work for me, too, and I'm not even getting an error message. But: using the switch `-activate com.apple.Terminal` works fine.

Comment: @Asmus Still not working for me...